# Service Call in client Side

Tags: javascript, vb.net, web-services, webservice-client

I need to call the service and retrieve the resulted data in call back function from it but I am getting js error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: InvoiceHTMLService is not defined.

Please help - below are my pages and class

My Aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="InvoiceHTML.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.InvoiceHTML" %>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Web Service call from client-side JavaScript</title>

    <script  type="text/javascript">
        function SendRequest() {
            debugger;
            InvoiceHTMLService.GetBillInvoiceHtmlData();
        }
        function OnComplete(arg) {
            alert(arg);
        }
        function OnTimeOut(arg) {
            alert("timeOut has occured");
        }
        function OnError(arg) {
            alert("error has occured: " + arg._message);
        }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Service/InvoiceHTMLService.asmx" />
    </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    <input type="text" value="" id="MyTextBox" />
    <input type="button" value="Send Request to the Web Service" 
           id="RequestButton" onclick="return SendRequest()" />
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my asmx page

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Drawing

Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

Imports System.IO
Imports ClassLibrary1


' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService()> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService()> _
Public Class InvoiceHTMLService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetBillInvoiceHtmlData() As Object
        Dim objDAOBill As DAOInvoice
        Dim Obj As Object

        objDAOBill = New DAOInvoice()

        Obj = objDAOBill.GetBillInvoiceHtmlData()
        Return Obj
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for it thanks everyone, I am posting the answer so it may can help others the service call from client side can be done by using the complete class name present in .asmx page.In my Case

```
<%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="InvoiceHTMLService.asmx.vb" Class="App.InvoiceHTMLService" %>
```

So I have to call the service in following way:

```
   function SendRequest() {

                App.InvoiceHTMLService.GetBillInvoiceHtmlData(callback);
            }
```